# In a d3 force-directed graph, how can I set node attributes in the tick function?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, d3-force-directed

In this force directed graph, I am creating a circle or square node depending on what group they have been assigned to.

I am creating these nodes with:

```
    const node = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#fff')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll()
      .data(nodes)
      .join((enter) => {
        return enter.append((d) => {
          console.log('join - d', d)

          if (d.group === 1) {
            const rectElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect')

            rectElement.setAttribute('width', 16)
            rectElement.setAttribute('height', 16)
            rectElement.setAttribute('fill', color(d.group))

            return rectElement
          } else {
            const circleElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle')

            circleElement.setAttribute('r', 16)
            circleElement.setAttribute('fill', color(d.group))

            return circleElement
          }
        })
      })
```

Since the square and circle nodes need different attributes, it seemed right to set them explicitly on the node with `.setAttribute`.

This logic worked when creating the nodes, but I am having trouble with the `tick` function and implementing something similar.

The function is:

```
    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y)

      //       node.each((d, i) => {
      //         console.log(` ~ node.each ~ d:`, i, d)
      //
      //         if (d.group === 1) {
      //           //
      //         } else {
      //           console.log(` ~ node.each ~ node:`, d3.select(this).node())
      //
      //           // d3.select(this).setAttribute('cx', d.x)
      //           // this.node().setAttribute('cx', d.x)
      //           // this.node().setAttribute('cy', d.y)
      //         }
      //       })

      node.attr('cx', (d) => d.x).attr('cy', (d) => d.y)
  }
```

I am chaining `.attr` to set the cx and cy attributes. The problem is these attributes do not apply to rect nodes. I have tried to use the `.each` function to be able to process each node and update the attributes. While I can get the data and index for each node, I cannot obtain the node itself to update the attributes.

The documentation (https://d3js.org/d3-selection/control-flow) says:

> with this as the current DOM element (nodes[I])

I tried calling `this.setAttribute('cy', d.y)`, but that does not work. I tried a few other variants, but haven't figured it out yet.

What am I missing? How have I misinterpreted the documentation? How can I set the attributes based on the node group?

```js
const width = 1000
    const height = 400
    const svgNS = d3.namespace('svg:text').space

    const node_data = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => ({
      group: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
    }))

    const edge_data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({
      source: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      target: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
    }))

    const links = edge_data.map((d) => ({ ...d }))
    const nodes = node_data.map((d, index) => ({ id: index, ...d }))
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

    const svg = d3.select('#chart')

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force(
        'link',
        d3
          .forceLink(links)
          .id((d) => d.id)
          .distance((d) => 100)
      )
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .on('tick', ticked)

    const link = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#999')
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.6)
      .selectAll()
      .data(links)
      .join('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', (d) => Math.sqrt(d.value))

    const node = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#fff')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll()
      .data(nodes)
      .join((enter) => {
        return enter.append((d) => {
          if (d.group === 1) {
            const rectElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect')

            rectElement.setAttribute('width', 16)
            rectElement.setAttribute('height', 16)
            rectElement.setAttribute('fill', color(d.group))

            return rectElement
          } else {
            const circleElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle')

            circleElement.setAttribute('r', 16)
            circleElement.setAttribute('fill', color(d.group))

            return circleElement
          }
        })
      })

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y)

      //       node.each((d, i) => {
      //         console.log(` ~ node.each ~ d:`, i, d)
      //
      //         if (d.group === 1) {
      //           //
      //         } else {
      //           console.log(` ~ node.each ~ node:`, d3.select(this).node())
      //
      //           // d3.select(this).setAttribute('cx', d.x)
      //           // this.node().setAttribute('cx', d.x)
      //           // this.node().setAttribute('cy', d.y)
      //         }
      //       })

      node.attr('cx', (d) => d.x).attr('cy', (d) => d.y)
  }
```

```css
.graph {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<svg ref="chart" id="chart" class="graph"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to modify the code so it will work.

The first is to do:

```
      node.each((d, i, n) => {
        if (d.group === 1) {
          n[i].setAttribute('x', d.x - 8)
          n[i].setAttribute('y', d.y - 8)
        } else {
          n[i].setAttribute('cx', d.x)
          n[i].setAttribute('cy', d.y)
        }
      })
```

The documentation also states:

> current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes)

Using the third argument passes (the list of node elements), can grab the node element at index i and set the attributes.

For the second option, the documentation was correct when it said:

> with this as the current DOM element (nodes[I])

The mistake in the documentation was not mentioning that arrow functions should not be used. Javascript does not allow `this` to be rebound in the way D3 needs it to be.

Passing a classic function, which does permit `this` to be bound, works.

```
      node.each(function (d) {
        if (d.group === 1) {
          this.setAttribute('x', d.x - 8)
          this.setAttribute('y', d.y - 8)
        } else {
          this.setAttribute('cx', d.x)
          this.setAttribute('cy', d.y)
        }
      })
```

This second option is used in the included code snippet.

```js
const width = 1000
    const height = 400
    const svgNS = d3.namespace('svg:text').space

    const node_data = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => ({
      group: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
    }))

    const edge_data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({
      source: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      target: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
    }))

    const links = edge_data.map((d) => ({ ...d }))
    const nodes = node_data.map((d, index) => ({ id: index, ...d }))
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

    const svg = d3.select('#chart')

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force(
        'link',
        d3
          .forceLink(links)
          .id((d) => d.id)
          .distance((d) => 100)
      )
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .on('tick', ticked)

    const link = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#999')
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.6)
      .selectAll()
      .data(links)
      .join('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', (d) => Math.sqrt(d.value))

    const node = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#fff')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll()
      .data(nodes)
      .join((enter) => {
        return enter.append((d) => {
          if (d.group === 1) {
            const rectElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect')

            rectElement.setAttribute('width', 16)
            rectElement.setAttribute('height', 16)
            rectElement.setAttribute('fill', color(d.group))

            return rectElement
          } else {
            const circleElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle')

            circleElement.setAttribute('r', 16)
            circleElement.setAttribute('fill', color(d.group))

            return circleElement
          }
        })
      })

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y)

      node.each(function (d) {
        if (d.group === 1) {
          this.setAttribute('x', d.x - 8)
          this.setAttribute('y', d.y - 8)
        } else {
          this.setAttribute('cx', d.x)
          this.setAttribute('cy', d.y)
        }
      })
  }
```

```css
.graph {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<svg ref="chart" id="chart" class="graph"></svg>
```